How can I create a Trait to represent all the type of data, except std::Any
What do I want
A Trait to represent all the type of data, like String,Vec<String>,i32, etc
Including some other complex data types, like Box<Arc<String>> and some of my customized structures...
But! It can not be std::Any....
Maybe it is not a Trait, I have no ideas
Why? It's weird!
Actually, I'm trying to implement a data flow engine with Rust.
Here is a example
String -> Node A -> i32

i32    -> Node B -> CustomStruct


Node A can convert the input string into i32 according to certain rules.
Node B converts a i32 input into a CustomStruct.

This means that I can connect Node B to Node A and then use the output of Node A as the input of Node B.
When I coding about this execution engine, I wrote some code like this
trait Node<Input, Output> {
    fn execute(&self, input: Input) -> Output;
}

struct NodeA;
impl Node<String, i32> for NodeA {
    fn execute(&self, input: String) -> i32 {
        todo!()
    }
}

struct NodeB;
impl Node<i32, CustomStruct> for NodeB {
    fn execute(&self, input: i32) -> CustomStruct {
        todo!()
    }
}

fn run() {
    let node_list = vec![NodeA, NodeB]; // Error here!

    let mut cur = "input_a".to_string();
    for node in node_list {
        cur = node.execute(cur); // I guess this line may also report an error?
    }

    println!("res: {:?}", cur);
}

Obviously, a compiler error will be given here, but I can't even specify the types of NodeA and NodeB.
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> crates/examples/src/demo.rs:20:33
   |
20 |     let node_list = vec![NodeA, NodeB];
   |                                 ^^^^^ expected `NodeA`, found `NodeB`

In addition, I guess there may also be a error with line 24, because the type of cur here may be String or i32, and the compiler may not be able to prove that the data type expected by the node variable in my for loop can match the type of cur. I'm not sure...
Why not std::Any
In fact, I tried using std::Any once, and it really solved the problem
But there are extremely large number of type conversions in the entire code. I feel that my type system has been completely broken.
This is not the code I want...
For now...
I m trying to use trait object to replace Input and Output, like this
trait Handlable {}

impl Handlable for String {}
impl Handlable for i32 {}
impl Handlable for CustomStruct {}

trait Node<Input, Output>
where
    Input: Handlable,
    Output: Handlable,
{
    fn execute(&self, input: Input) -> Output;
}

struct NodeA;
impl Node<String, i32> for NodeA {
    fn execute(&self, input: String) -> i32 {
        todo!()
    }
}

struct NodeB;
impl Node<i32, CustomStruct> for NodeB {
    fn execute(&self, input: i32) -> CustomStruct {
        todo!()
    }
}

type Input = Box<dyn Handlable>;
type Output = Box<dyn Handlable>;

fn run() {
    let node_list: Vec<Box<dyn Node<Input, Output>>> = vec![Box::new(NodeA), Box::new(NodeB)];

    let mut cur = "input_a".to_string();
    for node in node_list {
        cur = node.execute(cur);
    }

    println!("res: {:?}", cur);
}

Now the compiler reports an error that I can't solve.
error[E0277]: the trait bound `NodeA: Node<Box<(dyn Handlable + 'static)>, Box<(dyn Handlable + 'static)>>` is not satisfied
  --> crates/examples/src/demo.rs:35:61
   |
35 |     let node_list: Vec<Box<dyn Node<Input, Output>>> = vec![Box::new(NodeA), Box::new(NodeB)];
   |                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Node<Box<(dyn Handlable + 'static)>, Box<(dyn Handlable + 'static)>>` is not implemented for `NodeA`
   |
   = help: the trait `Node<String, i32>` is implemented for `NodeA`
   = note: required for the cast from `Box<NodeA>` to `Box<dyn Node<Box<(dyn Handlable + 'static)>, Box<(dyn Handlable + 'static)>>>`

I want to know if there is something wrong with my thinking, or something wrong with my design, or my requirement itself is not legal in Rust.
If you have any suggestions, or see similar functions, let me know, plz!

Are you building these chains of nodes at compile time only, or do you need to be able to build them dynamically at runtime?

@cdhowie I want to build it from configuration files at runtime

Since generics are not traits themselves (they are a kind of templates, from which the compiler defines multiple traits), you are unable to put them together into a vector, because vector has a certain and only data type, unless you use Box-wrapper. These questions explain it very well: Vector of objects belonging to a trait and Vector of generic trait objects.
So you have to implement something like this instead for the chain, where NodeA and NodeB implements the same trait:
let node_list: Vec<Box<dyn Node>> = vec![Box::new(NodeA), Box::new(NodeB)];

And one of the options for the trait Node is following, because since the type of cur in your example is uncertain, you also have to "Box" it and pass it to the execute function:
trait Node {
    fn execute(&self, input: Box<dyn Any>) -> Box<dyn Any>;
}

Please, note that std::any::Any is not a treatment in any case where you want to avoid a certain data type, its usage is quite limited (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html). On the other hand, it provides a helpful way to unpack the data type safely, with the help of downcast_ref. So you can implement your execution like this:
// Processing String -> i64
struct NodeA;

impl Node for NodeA {
    fn execute(&self, input: Box<dyn Any>) -> Box<dyn Any> {
        match input.downcast_ref::<String>() {
            Some(s) => Box::new(s.parse::<i64>().unwrap()),  // Put your code instead of s.parse::<i64>().unwrap()
            None => panic!("Error!"),
        }
    }
}

Putting all the ideas together we get a working example:
use std::any::Any;


// Node trait
trait Node {
    fn execute(&self, input: Box<dyn Any>) -> Box<dyn Any>;
}


// Processing String -> i64
struct NodeA;

impl Node for NodeA {
    fn execute(&self, input: Box<dyn Any>) -> Box<dyn Any> {
        match input.downcast_ref::<String>() {
            Some(s) => Box::new(s.parse::<i64>().unwrap()),
            None => panic!("Error!"),
        }
    }
}


// Processing i64 -> f64
struct NodeB;

impl Node for NodeB {
    fn execute(&self, input: Box<dyn Any>) -> Box<dyn Any> {
        match input.downcast_ref::<i64>() {
            Some(x) => Box::new(*x as f64),
            None => panic!("Error!"),
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    // Chain of nodes
    let node_list: Vec<Box<dyn Node>> = vec![Box::new(NodeA), Box::new(NodeB)];

    // Boxed initial value
    let mut cur: Box<dyn Any> = Box::new("12".to_string());

    // Processing in the chain
    for node in node_list.iter() {
        cur = node.execute(cur);
    }

    // Print the final result
    println!("{:?}", cur.downcast_ref::<f64>().unwrap());
}

I hope, this solves your issue. I also believe there are many ways to achieve the same result.

Thank you soooooooo much for your reply, it's helpful . I actually tried to use Any instead of my Input and Output, and it did work. But I was wondering if there was another way, because using Any would inevitably bring a lot of type conversions...
